# Gradle error: JSON standard does not allow such token (android studio 3.0)

Tags: android, gradle

i have this problem and relative solution, but i don't know why it works

I just upgraded to Android 3.0 and tried to compile my app. I have a lot of erro in gradle.build if i have this structure (i'll keep the relevant part)

```
android{
    ....
 }
dependencies {
  ....
 }
```

and the error is **JSON standard does not allow such token**

But if i change the structure to

```
android {
    ....

    dependencies {
     ....
     }
 }
```

(dependecies is INSIDE android object)

the error appears here:

```
compile '**com.android.support**:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile '**com.loopj.android**:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

with another error that says "< value> expected, got ':'"
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah things have changed. do it as follows

This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 vesion as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    debugCompile project(':debug-db')
    compile project(':tracker')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.7'
    compile 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:location-tracker-background:v1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but as you can see, in your answer, 'dependencies' json object is outside of 'android'.

Comment: yeah it has to be out side. Did u add the google() repos

Comment: yes i did. the problem is that if is outside i got error "on screen" but it will compile with no problem. it is strange

Comment: did twice but does not change. it's like is validating the file as json object but i can't find any option. going to remove android studio and reinstall it

Comment: uninstalling completely android studio and removing all the subdirs of Library, the error disappeared. thanks anyway